# torch: what is the structure for tensors of different sizes?

Tags: lua, lua-table, torch

table? but inserting big tensors to a table is not efficient, not even possible because of memory in my case. This works perfectly fine, but it's ugly:

```
local s_ = 0
s_ = s_ + 1; local X_py_1 = fromfile(('%s/x_py_%.2f.bin'):format(data_dir, scales[s_]))
s_ = s_ + 1; local X_py_2 = fromfile(('%s/x_py_%.2f.bin'):format(data_dir, scales[s_]))
s_ = s_ + 1; local X_py_3 = fromfile(('%s/x_py_%.2f.bin'):format(data_dir, scales[s_]))
s_ = s_ + 1; local X_py_4 = fromfile(('%s/x_py_%.2f.bin'):format(data_dir, scales[s_]))
s_ = s_ + 1; local X_py_5 = fromfile(('%s/x_py_%.2f.bin'):format(data_dir, scales[s_]))
s_ = s_ + 1; local X_py_6 = fromfile(('%s/x_py_%.2f.bin'):format(data_dir, scales[s_]))
X_py = {X_py_1, X_py_2, X_py_3, X_py_4, X_py_5, X_py_6}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add a part of your sentence, except if you wanted to begin with "table ?" :p

Comment: I'm answering my own question, but ok, full sentence is: is it table?

Answer (score 0):

show my code.. please help to you

```
X_py = {X_py_1, X_py_2, X_py_3, X_py_4, X_py_5, X_py_6}
for i, v in ipairs(X_py) do
    v = fromfile(('%s/x_py_%.2f.bin'):format(data_dir, scales[i-1]))
end
```

simply using table, do you want it?

Comment: no, this doesn't work. after that, X_py table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

okay, this simply works:

```
X_py = {}
for s, scale in ipairs(scales) do
  X_py[s] = fromfile(('%s/x_py_%.2f.bin'):format(data_dir, scale))
end
```